# How to combine result of multiple Linq Expressions into one Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, linq-expressions

I have a list of Linq Expressions `List<Expression>` where each expression type (the type the expression would return) is either `Item` or `Item[]`.

I'm trying to write some code that would take mentioned collection as an input parameter and produce a Linq Expression that would return one list (or array) of items (`Item[]`).

Here is an abstract example:

```
public static string[] GetStrings()
{
    return new[]
        {
            "first",
            "second",
            "third"
        };
}

public static string GetString()
{
    return "single1";
}

private void SOExample()
{
    var expressions = new List<Expression>
    {
        Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("GetString")),
        Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("GetStrings")), 
        Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("GetString")),
        Expression.Call(GetType().GetMethod("GetStrings"))
    };

    // some magic code here
    var combined = SomeMagicHere(expressions);
}


private Expression SomeMagicHere(List<Expression> expressions)
{
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
    {
        if (expression.Type.IsArray)
        {
            // Use array's elements
        } 
        else
        {
            // Use expression
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to make is to produce one Expression that would return a list of `Item` (strings in my example) from provided list.

Comment: an expression is rarely used by itself, and even less rarely when not part of a `LambdaExpression`. Is there a specific reason this is using `Expression` rather than... well, maybe just reflection, maybe delegates, etc. `Expression` doesn't feel an obvious choice here. Also: what are you looking for in a result: do you want it to *evaluate* the methods, combining their results? or build an `Expression` that would, when compiled etc, evaluate the tree? or...? basically: what would your ideal result look like here? Also: what is the target caller? (it matters: ORM callers won't like this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems a very odd scenario, and in most cases I would expect to see use of raw reflection (or maybe delegates) rather than `Expression` here - it isn't an obvious fit. But: you can do that by turning the expressions into a *block* that each call `Add` or `AddRange` to append values into the list. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

static class Program
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return "single1";
    }
    public static string[] GetStrings()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "first",
            "second",
            "third"
        };
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var expressions = new List<Expression>
        {
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetString")),
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetStrings")), 
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetString")),
            Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetStrings"))
        };

        // some magic code here
        var combined = SomeMagicHere(expressions);

        // show it works
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<string>>>(combined);
        var list = lambda.Compile()();
    }
    private static Expression SomeMagicHere(List<Expression> expressions)
    {
        List<Expression> blockContents = new List<Expression>();
        var var = Expression.Variable(typeof(List<string>), "list");
        blockContents.Add(Expression.Assign(var,
            Expression.New(typeof(List<string>))));
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            if (expression.Type.IsArray)
            {
                blockContents.Add(Expression.Call(
                    var, var.Type.GetMethod("AddRange"), expression));
            }
            else
            {
                blockContents.Add(Expression.Call(var,
                    var.Type.GetMethod("Add"), expression));
            }
        }
        blockContents.Add(var); // last statement in a block is the effective
                                // value of the block
        return Expression.Block(new[] {var}, blockContents);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your reply - that's exactly what I was looking for. I create this expression as a part of bigger expression that eventually gets compiled and executed. The code is used inside custom language compiler :)

Comment: @Hubert I must be crazy, but when I need that I just do it direct on `ILGenerator` ;p

Comment: The idea of using Linq Expressions is not mine, I had to follow what I found (ANTLR + Linq Expressions) :) Anyway thanks a lot, I feel I have to get more into Linq Expressions :)